# Update datagridview with threads

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, thread-safety

I have the following code at button.click sub, it takes data from one access DB and load the rows one by one into a SQL DB, the line that inserts code is commented because it's already tested.

```
Dim cSQL As New SqlConnection(conSQL)
    Dim fecha1, fecha2 As Date
    Dim strfecha1, strfecha2 As String
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        fecha1 = CDate(dr.Item(0))
        fecha2 = CDate(dr.Item(18))
        strfecha1 = fecha1.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss tt").Replace(".", "")
        strfecha2 = fecha2.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss tt").Replace(".", "")
        selSQL = "insert into ttransactionlog1 ([OccurDateTime],[NodeID],[Kind],[UUID],[UserID],[FirstName],[LastName],[MI],[Department],[Rank],[CardID],[CreateDateTime],[LeftRight],[HD],[RotationDegree],[StableTimeInterval],[DecisionTimeInterval],[Message],[PIN]) values " + _
            "('" + strfecha1 + "'," + _
            dr.Item(1).ToString + "," + _
            dr.Item(2).ToString + "," + _
            dr.Item(4).ToString + ",'" + _
            dr.Item(3).ToString + "','" + _
            dr.Item(5).ToString + "','" + _
            dr.Item(6).ToString + "','" + _
            dr.Item(7).ToString + "','" + _
            dr.Item(8).ToString + "','" + _
            dr.Item(9).ToString + "','" + _
            dr.Item(10).ToString + "','" + _
            strfecha2 + "'," + _
            dr.Item(16).ToString + "," + _
            dr.Item(14).ToString + "," + _
            dr.Item(15).ToString + "," + _
            dr.Item(12).ToString + "," + _
            dr.Item(13).ToString + ",'" + _
            dr.Item(11).ToString + "'," + _
            dr.Item(17).ToString + ")"
        daSQL.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(selSQL, cSQL)
        'cSQL.Open()
        'daSQL.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'cSQL.Close()
        'DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, dr.ItemArray)
        'If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 10 Then
        '    DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(10)
        'End If
        procesar = New Thread(AddressOf Me.actGrilla)
        procesar.IsBackground = True
        procesar.Start(dr)
        'actGrilla(dr)
    Next
```

I want to update a DGV showing the inserted datarow in it's top position and up to 10 records in screen, for that I'm trying to make a sub in a new thread in this way.

```
Sub actGrilla(ByVal dr As DataRow)
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Dim uud As New llamaactGrilla(AddressOf actGrilla)
        Invoke(uud, dr)
    Else
        DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, dr.ItemArray)
        If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 10 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(10)
        End If
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

My problem is when I try this way, the code always gone by invokeRequired true and collapse by memory fault (are about 5000 records), and when I try doing without a thread, writing the "else" code inside the for cycle the program eventually collapse with cotextswitchdeadlock.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What version of .Net?

Comment: The code is made in .Net 3.5

Comment: I would suggest a BackGroundWorker, use them quite a bit and works great in anything I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little research the problem was solved.

1st. I replace the cycle with the thead call.

```
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        procesar = New Thread(AddressOf procesoFondo)
        procesar.Start(dt)
    End If
```

2nd. put the cycle in the new function "procesoFondo", the lines that insert the code in the SQL DB are here, into the cycle I call the new sub delegate.

```
    Dim daSQL As New SqlDataAdapter

    Dim cSQL As New SqlConnection(conSQL)
    Dim fecha1, fecha2 As Date
    Dim strfecha1, strfecha2 As String
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        fecha1 = CDate(dr.Item(0))
        fecha2 = CDate(dr.Item(18))
        strfecha1 = fecha1.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss tt").Replace(".", "")
        strfecha2 = fecha2.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss tt").Replace(".", "")
        selSQL = "insert into ttransactionlog1 ([OccurDateTime],[NodeID],[Kind],[UUID],[UserID],[FirstName],[LastName],[MI],[Department],[Rank],[CardID],[CreateDateTime],[LeftRight],[HD],[RotationDegree],[StableTimeInterval],[DecisionTimeInterval],[Message],[PIN]) values " + _
            "('" + strfecha1 + "'," + _
            dr.Item(1).ToString + "," + _
            dr.Item(2).ToString + "," + _
            dr.Item(4).ToString + ",'" + _
            dr.Item(3).ToString + "','" + _
            dr.Item(5).ToString + "','" + _
            dr.Item(6).ToString + "','" + _
            dr.Item(7).ToString + "','" + _
            dr.Item(8).ToString + "','" + _
            dr.Item(9).ToString + "','" + _
            dr.Item(10).ToString + "','" + _
            strfecha2 + "'," + _
            dr.Item(16).ToString + "," + _
            dr.Item(14).ToString + "," + _
            dr.Item(15).ToString + "," + _
            dr.Item(12).ToString + "," + _
            dr.Item(13).ToString + ",'" + _
            dr.Item(11).ToString + "'," + _
            dr.Item(17).ToString + ")"

        'Inserta el dato en SQL
        daSQL.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(selSQL, cSQL)
        cSQL.Open()
        daSQL.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cSQL.Close()

        'Llama invocacion de llenado de gridview
        add_datos_gv(dr)

        'Llama invocacion estado proceso
        estado_hilo()
    Next
```

The delegates (1+ for the label that shows the state of the thread) are.

```
Delegate Sub set_gv(ByVal dr As DataRow)
Delegate Sub set_lb()
```

Finally, the delegates update the info in DGV

```
 Private Sub add_datos_gv(ByVal dr As DataRow)
    If DataGridView1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New set_gv(AddressOf add_datos_gv)
        Invoke(d, dr)
    Else
        DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, dr.ItemArray)
        If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 10 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(10)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub estado_hilo()
    If Label1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim l As New set_lb(AddressOf estado_hilo)
        Invoke(l)
    Else
        Label1.Text = procesar.ThreadState.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `InvokeRequired`. Windows has a [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to make threaded access to UI controls much easier. I'm not versed in VB.Net but I'll take a stab at it:

```
Dim Sync as SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current

Sub actGrilla(ByVal dr As DataRow)
    // Post is an async method that queues work on the UI thread
    // Alternatively, use Send instead as a blocking call
    Sync.Post(
          // I do not know the correct syntax in VB to set this up
```

`// but` [`here is a sample`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998734/vb-net-two-different-approaches-to-generic-cross-threaded-operations-which-is-b)

> ```
>         DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, dr.ItemArray)
>         If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 10 Then
>             DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(10)
>         End If
>         DataGridView1.Refresh()
> ```

```
     , Nothing)
End Sub
```